# updating Lagrange multipliers using subgradient method

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have applied correctly the Lagrange algorithm on a toy example given by (Fisher 1985), however, when I tried to apply it to a bigger problem, I did not get any improvement in terms of solution.

The lagrange multipliers took three dimensions. Let's call it $ λ_{htp}$.
I have relaxed the following constraint given that the problem is a minimization problem:

[image: $\sum_{w}{Q_{whtp}} + QU_{htp} \ge D_{htp} \ \ ∀ h,t,p$]

Then I have written it in the objective function as follows:

[image: $\sum_{h}\sum_{t}\sum_{p}\lambda_{htp}*[ D_{htp} - \sum_{w}{Q_{whtp}} + QU_{htp}] $]

[image: $\lambda_{htp}^{k+1}$ = $\max \left(0,λ_{htp}^{k}+ step^{k}*[ D_{htp} - \sum_{w}{Q_{whtp}} + QU_{htp}] \right) \ \ ∀ \ h,t,p$]

[image: $step^{k}$= $γ* [(\left( UB^{}-LB^{}\right) $ $\div$ $ \left( \sum_{h}\sum_{t}\sum_{p}[ D_{htp} - \sum_{w}{Q_{whtp}} + QU_{htp}] \right)]$]

I implemented the algorithm in Python with Gurobi solver. I have run it multiple times, and some observation was taken, the step size is decreasing (which is good), the algorithm is iterating, the scalar $γ $ is decreasing, the objective function is not improving (increasing), the $λ_{htp}$ is not converging and it is giving incorrect results.

Here is a part of the implementation and calculation of $λ_{htp}$  and $stepsize$. I am wondering where the issue is exactly.

```
obj_relaxed_const = (sum(lamda[h,t,p] for h in range(customer) for\ 
p in range(products)\
for t in range(months)) * (sum(demand[h,t,p] for h in \
range(healthcenters) for p in \
range(products)for t in range(months))-(sum(QW_wh_[w,h,t,p] for w \
in range(warehouses) for h in range(customer) for p in\
range(products) for t in range(months))) - sum(QU_h_[h,t,p] for h \
in range(customer) for p in  range(products) for t in \
range(months))))
------
b_Axr = (sum(demand[h,t,p] for h in range(customer) for p in \
range(products)for t \ 
in range(months))-sum(QW_wh_[w,h,t,p].x for w in 
range(warehouses) for h in \ 
range(customer) for p in range(products) for t in range(months))- \ 
sum(QU_h_[h,t,p].x for h in range(customer) for p in \
range(products) for t in \ 
range(months)))
```

---

```
if abs(UB_b-LB_b)/ UB_b <= 0.001 or gamma <= 0.001:
    break
else:
    for h in range(customer):
        for t in range(months):
            for p in range(products):
                    lamda[h,t,p] = max(0, lamda[h,t,p] + stepsize * (demand[h, t, p]\
                     - sum(QW_wh_[w, h, t, p].x for w in range(warehouses)) - QU_h_[h, t, p].x))
                    
     stepsize = gamma*(UB_b-LB_b)/((LA.norm(b_Axr))**2)
```